# tune2fs: No such device or address while trying to open /dev/sda1?

Tags: fsck, read-only, tune2fs

My hard disk is going to bad:

```
Apr  3 20:26:48 207 kernel: aacraid: Host adapter abort request (0,0,0,0)
Apr  3 20:26:48 207 kernel: aacraid: Host adapter reset request. SCSI hang ?
Apr  3 20:26:58 207 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 360s
Apr  3 20:26:58 207 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: SCSI error: return code = 0x06000000
Apr  3 20:26:58 207 kernel: end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 4358861306
Apr  3 20:26:58 207 kernel: EXT3-fs error (device sda1): ext3_free_branches: Read failure, inode=246590279, block=544857659
Apr  3 20:26:58 207 kernel: Aborting journal on device sda1.

Apr  3 20:33:48 207 kernel: aacraid: Host adapter abort request (0,0,0,0)
Apr  3 20:33:48 207 kernel: aacraid: Host adapter reset request. SCSI hang ?
Apr  3 20:33:58 207 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 360s
Apr  3 20:33:58 207 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: SCSI error: return code = 0x06000000
Apr  3 20:33:58 207 kernel: end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 34
Apr  3 20:33:58 207 kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 0
Apr  3 20:33:58 207 kernel: lost page write due to I/O error on sda1
Apr  3 20:33:58 207 kernel: EXT3-fs error (device sda1) in ext3_reserve_inode_write: Journal has aborted

Apr  3 20:44:18 207 kernel: aacraid: Host adapter abort request (0,0,0,0)
Apr  3 20:44:18 207 kernel: aacraid: Host adapter reset request. SCSI hang ?
Apr  3 20:44:30 207 kernel: ext3_abort called.
Apr  3 20:44:30 207 kernel: EXT3-fs error (device sda1): ext3_journal_start_sb: Detected aborted journal
Apr  3 20:44:30 207 kernel: Remounting filesystem read-only
```

/dev/sda1 mounted to /data. The system give me the "Input/Output error" when I `cd` to some folders.

I'm going to run `fsck` on this device follow the steps below:

> 1. stop all services access to /data
> 2. unmount the /data
> 3. tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sda1
> 4. e2fsck -fcy /dev/sda1
> 5. tune2fs -j /dev/sda1

but I got the following when run step 3:

```
# tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sda1 
tune2fs 1.39 (29-May-2006)
tune2fs: No such device or address while trying to open /dev/sda1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

I backed up some parts of data on this. What should I do now?

P/S: This disk has been used about for 1 year. My system requires high read/write intensity, should I change to SSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid in this case you are going to have to reboot the box. The disk controller is having issues talking to the drive. Once you reboot you very well may have to preform a fsck. Once that is done I would check the SMART data:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki

That can give you a better idea what state the disk is in and help you plan your next move.

Comment: OK. I have had to reboot. The preliminary cause is RAID degraded. Adaptec Storage Manager give me the below info: `Device #1
         Device is a Hard drive
         State                              : Rebuilding
`. Backed up the data, I'm going to replace the bad device.